# Methods for interacting with a Pervasive SQL database

Tags: c#, orm, data-access-layer, pervasive

I'm in the process of developing a web interface to a service business management application that uses a Pervasive SQL database to store information (not my choice, by the way). At the moment, I'm using the official Pervasive SqlClient implementation with a custom set of query generation classes so I can write code like:

```
new SelectQuery().From("CUSTOMER").Fields("CUSTOMERNBR", "NAME");
```

It's working fine so far, but I'm running into little problems here and there. Rather than keep going in this direction, I'd rather use a proven DAL. However, I'm not having very much luck in finding a DAL system that can interact with a Pervasive database.

Opf3 has a Pervasive storage provider, but I've never heard of that framework before and the website only displays the Pervasive v8 logo, while I need something that will work with v9.5 and, in the future, v10.

I tried writing an NHibernate provider, but that ended up being even more of a headache than my current query generation system.

What do you suggest? I'm on a very rushed timeline, so I'd like something that will integrate as easily as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pervasive.SQL has a pretty solid ADO Adapter, and rocks over ODBC in most cases; I have used if successufully for years, but not without the headaches of Pervasive's syntax.  In Pervasive's defense their relational engine does comply with SQL-92 and most of SQL-99.

What I am curious about is what parts of the syntax are you having a problem with, what is causing your grief?

What version of Pervasive's engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using Pervasive v9.5 (currently the only version that our desktop application supports). The syntax problems come mostly from ORM systems wanting to use LIMIT instead of TOP or brackets instead of quotes. OPF3's PSQL provider solves these issues, though, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the ODBC drivers from Pervasive - they must be solid or Pervasive would be out of business by now. And most higher level abstraction software can deal with ODBC-level data. I think that would be your best bet, if you feel you really need to abstract it further than the ODBC itself.

Comment: The problem with this is that the DAL/ORM would need to know Pervasive-specific SQL syntax. That's the problem I ran into with NHibernate. It could use the Pervasive SqlClient just fine, but I ran into issues when trying to get NHibernate to "speak" PSQL's language.

Comment: ODBC should extract out the Pervasive anomalies - that's what it's for. It runs on generic SQL.

Comment: Lots of products that small businesses rely on are not what anyone would consider solid, but businesses still rely on them so they stay in business.  Generally speaking though the ADO library will work better than ODBC and is more portable.